# How do I keep doubling a number through a for loop in Go?

Tags: for-loop, go

I've tried many different things, to no avail. This is a simple thing but I'm struggling with it, and can't find much helpful resources.

Here's part of what I have tried:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
        i := (i * 2)
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you expecting to happen? What do you get? Note that you are using the loop index as your doubling target, do u mean that?

Comment: I also tried doing it with another variable but go 2, 4, 6, 8... instead somehow. In any case a good answer has been given now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *are* doubling `i`, but you're creating a new `i` every iteration, with with the value from the `i` used in the for loop clause.

You probably want something like

```
x := 1
for i := 1; i < 10; i++ {
    fmt.Println(x)
    x *= 2
}
```

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I need. Except the Println should be above x*=2 to include the 1. :)